# Dbghelp versions?

Tags: dbghelp

I've been doing some research on Dbghelp, trying to determine whether or not I need to go through the hassle of updating it. I'm currently on version 6.12, does anyone have a change log for 6.12 to 6.13.X? Or if not, do you know if anything important was changed?

Answer (score 0):

6.12 is the most recent version MS lists on their [version page](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/ms679294.aspx).

Updating isn't much hassle using the Microsoft installer for the [Debugging Tools for Windows](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/hardware/hh852365) though.

Comment: The page is out of date, the current version is 6.13.X. I've also done the reading on the microsoft site, I can't find any kind of a change log, which is why I'm posting.